# The datepicker on select option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

The option onSelect in a jquery datepicker. The datepicker I have, only is execute the first time. When I select a different date, it does not do anything. I want that every time a user selects a new date, the onSelect option to be executed

Comment: It should. Post some code or a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$('#date_start').datepicker(
{
    onSelect: function(dateObj, instance) { 
                alert("h1");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`onSelect` Works fine.

```
$('#date_start').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(value) { alert(value); }
});
```

The `value` variable has the current selected date for each time user select a new date of datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.

The onSelect was right. The problem was some malfuctioning code in the onSelect function, that prevent the code to run.

In these cases, just comment out the function inside the onSelect option, and just make an alert. 
That will show you where the problem is.